# ¿Como puedo unir dos partes de un objeto Json en uno solo?

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, ionic2

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con ionic 2, en la `page1` solicito una información de una base de datos, y retorna un arreglo con objetos con una estructura como la siguiente:

```
data = [{
  id: "Id del registro",
  propiedad1 : "mi propiedad 1",
  propiedad2 : "mi propiedad 2",
  propiedad5 : "mi propiedad 5",
  propiedad7 : "mi propiedad 7",
  propiedad8 : "mi propiedad 8",
  propiedad10 : "mi propiedad 10",
  propiedad15 : "mi propiedad 15",
  propiedad16 : "mi propiedad 16",
  propiedad18 : "mi propiedad 18"
},
{...},
Miles de elementos más...];
```

En este arreglo me pueden llegar miles de elementos, la razón por la que no pido todo las propiedades del objeto `Json`, al ir a la `page2` le paso unos de los elemento del arreglo data, que vendría siendo uno de estos objetos, en la `page2` solicito la información faltante a la base de datos, me debe retornar un arreglo de un solo elemento con las propiedades que me faltan del objeto que se le paso como parámetro a la `page2`

**Ejemplo:**

```
respuesta = [{
    propiedad3 : "mi propiedad 3",
    propiedad4 : "mi propiedad 4",
    propiedad6 : "mi propiedad 6",
    propiedad9 : "mi propiedad 9",
    propiedad11 : "mi propiedad 11",
    propiedad12 : "mi propiedad 12",
    propiedad13 : "mi propiedad 13",
    propiedad14 : "mi propiedad 14"
}];
```

Ahora, lo que quiero es unir en un solo objeto Json todas las propiedades.
lo que intente fue lo siguiente

**# page2.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ModalController, ViewController, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { DetalleEventoPage } from '../detalle-evento/detalle-evento';
//import { AgregarEventoPage } from '../agregar-evento/agregar-evento';


/**
 * Generated class for the ContenidoDisciplinaPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-contenido-disciplina',
  templateUrl: 'contenido-disciplina.html',
})
export class ContenidoDisciplinaPage {
  parte1ObjetoJson;
  miObjetoJson : {
   id ?: string,
   propiedad1 ?: string,
   propiedad2 ?: string,
   propiedad3 ?: string,
   propiedad4 ?: string,
   propiedad5 ?: string,
   propiedad6 ?: string,
   propiedad7 ?: string,
   propiedad8 ?: string,
   propiedad9 ?: string,
   propiedad10 ?: string,
   propiedad11 ?: string,
   propiedad12 ?: string,
   propiedad13 ?: string,
   propiedad14 ?: string,
   propiedad15 ?: string,
   propiedad16 ?: string,
   propiedad17 ?: string,
   propiedad18 ?: string
}
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController , public http: Http , public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.parte1ObjetoJson= navParams.get('parte1ObjetoJson');
    this.miObjetoJson = this.parte1ObjetoJson;
    console.log(this.miObjetoJson);

    let body=JSON.stringify({id: this.parte1ObjetoJson.id});
    let url= "miURL";

    this.http.post( url,body).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(parte2=> {
        this.miObjetoJson = parte2;
        console.log(this.miObjetoJson);
    });
  }
}
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

**console 1:**

```
{ propiedad1 : "mi propiedad 1", propiedad2 : "mi propiedad 2", propiedad5 : "mi propiedad 5", propiedad7 : "mi propiedad 7", propiedad8 : "mi propiedad 8", propiedad10 : "mi propiedad 10", propiedad15 : "mi propiedad 15", propiedad16 : "mi propiedad 16", propiedad18 : "mi propiedad 18"}
```

**console 2:**

```
{ propiedad3 : "mi propiedad 3", propiedad4 : "mi propiedad 4", propiedad6 : "mi propiedad 6", propiedad9 : "mi propiedad 9", propiedad11 : "mi propiedad 11", propiedad12 : "mi propiedad 12", propiedad13 : "mi propiedad 13", propiedad14 : "mi propiedad 14"}
```

¿Como logro unir estas dos partes?

Comment: con Javascript para concatenar dos objetos json es de la siguiente forma:  `var objetoConcatenado  = objectA.concat(objectB);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign), el cual se utiliza para copiar los valores de todas la propiedades enumerables de uno o más objetos fuente a un objeto destino.

```js
let obj_1 = { propiedad1 : "mi propiedad 1", propiedad2 : "mi propiedad 2", propiedad5 : "mi propiedad 5", propiedad7 : "mi propiedad 7", propiedad8 : "mi propiedad 8", propiedad10 : "mi propiedad 10", propiedad15 : "mi propiedad 15", propiedad16 : "mi propiedad 16", propiedad18 : "mi propiedad 18"};
let obj_2 = { propiedad3 : "mi propiedad 3", propiedad4 : "mi propiedad 4", propiedad6 : "mi propiedad 6", propiedad9 : "mi propiedad 9", propiedad11 : "mi propiedad 11", propiedad12 : "mi propiedad 12", propiedad13 : "mi propiedad 13", propiedad14 : "mi propiedad 14"};

let obj_unidos = Object.assign(obj_1, obj_2);

console.log(obj_unidos);
```

Comment: Vale recordar que la copia que hace es "shadow copy" si este objeto tiene subobjetos y se cambia algún valor será modificado ya que mantiene una referencia

Comment: Ojo con el object assign porque en tu ejemplo obj_1 también fue modificado